# OpenFileDialog not showing contents of files

Tags: c#, image, openfiledialog

I have application that will edit images. It's working pretty fine, but one thing isn't working as I would want. When I want to upload an image, I use `OpenFileDialog`. The filter is set to .bmp and .jpg. But when I am browsing the files where I have the Images.jpg It doesn't show anything, but when I type exact name file into the search bar I can open it.

Block of code:

```
OpenFileDialog OtevritSoubor = new OpenFileDialog();
OtevritSoubor.Filter = "Obrazek(*.bmp, *.jpg)|*.bmp, *.jpg";
OtevritSoubor.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Use semicolon, not comma: `"Obrazek(*.bmp,*.jpg)|*.bmp;*.jpg"`

Comment: As noted in documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks